# Jasper report to html not displaying background color

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to export jasper report to html. My title,detail band column headers has background colors. The report has all the colors when I am checking it in jasperviewer, but after exporting to html the background colors in the html reports are not getting displayed.(only for detail) They are not there even in the source code.

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport
name="monthlyStats" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="400" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
      <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
      <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
      <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
      <style name="table">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#1E90FF">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE0FF">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 1">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#1E90FF">
            <box>
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE0FF">
            <box>
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
      </style>
      <style name="table 2">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#000000">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFE6E6">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
      </style>
      <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1"/>
      <subDataset name="Table Dataset 2"/>
      <subDataset name="Table Dataset 3"/>
      <parameter name="devicename" class="java.lang.String" />
      <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select DATEPART(MONTH,rm_devus_enddt) as month,
CASE when DATEPART(MONTH,rm_devus_enddt)=2
      then
            SUM((DATEDIFF(HOUR,rm_devus_startdt,rm_devus_enddt)*100.0)/(28.0*24.0))
      else
            CASE when (DATEPART(MONTH,rm_devus_enddt)%2)!=0
                 then
                        SUM((DATEDIFF(HOUR,rm_devus_startdt,rm_devus_enddt)*100.0)/(31.0*24.0))
                  else
                        SUM((DATEDIFF(HOUR,rm_devus_startdt,rm_devus_enddt)*100.0)/(30.0*24.0))
                  end
      end  as freepercent 
from deviceusage where rm_device_id=(select rm_device_id from device where rm_device_name=$P{devicename})
and rm_devus_enddt is not NULL GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,rm_devus_enddt);]]>
      </queryString>
      <field name="month" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
      <field name="freepercent" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
      <background>
            <band/>
      </background>
      <title>
            <band height="41">
                  <frame>
                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-26" width="595" height="53" backcolor="#006699"/>
                        <image>
                              <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="225" height="48"/>
                              <imageExpression><![CDATA["../logo/RDLOGO.JPG"]]></imageExpression>
                        </image>
                  </frame>
                  <rectangle>
                        <reportElement x="-20" y="33" width="595" height="5" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#006699"/>
                  </rectangle>
            </band>
      </title>
      <pageHeader>
            <band/>
      </pageHeader>
      <columnHeader>
            <band height="67">
                  <frame>
                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="16" y="34" width="511" height="33" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#000000"/>
                  </frame>
                  <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="58" y="47" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#F0F0F0" />
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                              <font size="13" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Month]]></text>
                  </staticText>
                  <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="221" y="47" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#F0F0F0" />
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                              <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[%free]]></text>
                  </staticText>
                  <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="371" y="47" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#F0F0F0" />
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                              <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[%used]]></text>
                  </staticText>
            </band>
      </columnHeader>
```

NOTE: I'm getting the background color for title but not in column header and detail.

Comment: You can read the @mdahlman's answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953705/ireport-import-background-image)

Comment: @Alex that question & answer is related to background images and my question is related to background colors.

Comment: You'll probably have to post some .jrxml. It sounds like you understand things conceptually, but there's some sort of bug in the report definition.

Comment: @mdahlman hmm.. If there is a bug in jrxml report, it should not come for jasperviewer also. But I'm able to get the desired output in jasper viewer but not in html. Find the jrxml code added. NOTE: this is generated using iReports

Comment: That's a good point. What do you get when generating XHTML? It could be a limitation of the HTML exporter. Try setting the background color for each text element (now you only have it set for the frame).

Comment: I'm able to get the color when I'm setting for text element in column header and detail. But it is not the background for the whole rectangle, it is coming for every text element seperately which means in blocks. I want the same output as of the page title where I'm getting the color.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into similar issue with excel export. It turns out the export only supports certain color palettes.  You'll have to look for html exporter color palette and change your colors to one that on that list.